# How to create an UITableView with an intrinsic Height in Swift 5 using UIKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

I ran into a problem while using `UITableViews`.

> AutoLayout requires a **fixed Height Constraint** for the UITableView, so the **Height does not change** when I add or remove `TableViewCells`.

My Problem is, that I am using a `TableView` **inside** a `ScrollView`. This is not really great since **both elements are scrollable**.

> My Plan is to **always resize the TableView** in relation to its content Height. In this case the TableView can **never get scrolled**.

My Idea so far was the following, but because of some reason, it does not really work:

```swift
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
```

If you have **any ideas** on how to fix this, please comment down below. *Simpler Solutions without class extensions, etc. are preferred;)*

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something along the lines of:

```swift
final class AutoSizingTableView: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return contentSize
    }
}
```

Basically what this does is set an intrinsicContentSize equal to the contentSize when the data of the tableview is reloaded, or if the contentSize changes.

However you have to ask yourself the question: If I don't need dequeuing logic, do I actually need a tableview?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is working perfectly. However I Have still one questions left: Is there any way to disable the Missing Constraint Warning in Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, you can set a height constraint with its priority set to medium (~500). That should not break this class, and should fix your warning. If you're feeling cheeky you can also set a required constraint for the height, and check the `remove at runtime` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `updateViewConstraints()` method in your UIViewController and set the new height of `tableView` as follows:

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    tableViewHeightConstraint?.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

And call `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` when you need to recreate your `tableView` with a new height.